# Missing values imputation for categorical variables in Python

Tags: python, r, missing-data, imputation

I'm seeking for a good imputation method for this case.
I have a dataframe with categorical variables and missing data like the following one:

```
    import pandas as pd


var1 = ['a','a','a','c','e',None]
var2 = ['p1','p1','p1','p2','p3','p1']
var3 = ['o1','o1','o1','o2','o3','o1']

df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':var1,'v2':var2,'v3':var3})
```

I'm looking for an imputation method in python (could be R as well) that support just categorical variables. The idea is to  predict var1 given var2 and var3.
For example, if we want to predict the NONE value that is in var1. We certainly know that the probability of var1='a' given var2='p1' and var3 = 'o1' is 1. I mean, P(var1='a' / (var2='p1',var3='o1') = 3/3 = 1. I thought about programming something like conditional modes but maybe someone already programmed this or there's a better algorithm for this. 
I just have 3 categorical variables with multiple categories, whose missing values are MCAR. It is very important to mention that my dataset has around a more than a million rows (and about 10% of NAs).

Do you have anything to recommend me?

Thanks in advance,
Tomas

Comment: You could use: `pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.fillna`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use K nearest neighbors imputation.

Here's one example in R:

```
library(DMwR)

var1 = c('a','a','a','c','e',NA)
var2 = c('p1','p1','p1','p2','p3','p1')
var3 = c('o1','o1','o1','o2','o3','o1')

df = data.frame('v1'=var1,'v2'=var2,'v3'=var3)
df

knnOutput <- DMwR::knnImputation(df, k = 5) 
knnOutput
```

Output:

```
  v1 v2 v3
1  a p1 o1
2  a p1 o1
3  a p1 o1
4  c p2 o2
5  e p3 o3
6  a p1 o1
```

**UPDATE:**

KNN doesn't work well for large data sets.  Two options for large data sets are Multinomial imputation and Naive Bayes imputation. Multinomial imputation is a little easier, because you don't need to convert the variables into dummy variables. The Naive Bayes implementation I have shown below is a little more work because it requires you to convert to dummy variables. Below, I show how to fit each of these in R:

```
# make data with 6M rows
var1 = rep(c('a','a','a','c','e',NA), 10**6)
var2 = rep(c('p1','p1','p1','p2','p3','p1'), 10**6)
var3 = rep(c('o1','o1','o1','o2','o3','o1'), 10**6)
df = data.frame('v1'=var1,'v2'=var2,'v3'=var3)

####################################################################
## Multinomial imputation
library(nnet)
# fit multinomial model on only complete rows
imputerModel = multinom(v1 ~ (v2+ v3)^2, data = df[!is.na(df$v1), ])

# predict missing data
predictions = predict(imputerModel, newdata = df[is.na(df$v1), ])

####################################################################
#### Naive Bayes
library(naivebayes)
library(fastDummies)
# convert to dummy variables
dummyVars <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(df, 
                                     select_columns = c("v2", "v3"), 
                                     ignore_na = TRUE)
head(dummyVars)
```

The `dummy_cols` function adds dummy variables to the existing data frame, so now we will use only columns 4:9 as our training data.

```
#     v1 v2 v3 v2_p1 v2_p2 v2_p3 v3_o1 v3_o2 v3_o3
# 1    a p1 o1     1     0     0     1     0     0
# 2    a p1 o1     1     0     0     1     0     0
# 3    a p1 o1     1     0     0     1     0     0
# 4    c p2 o2     0     1     0     0     1     0
# 5    e p3 o3     0     0     1     0     0     1
# 6 <NA> p1 o1     1     0     0     1     0     0
```

```
# create training set
X_train <- na.omit(dummyVars)[, 4:ncol(dummyVars)]
y_train <- na.omit(dummyVars)[, "v1"]

X_to_impute <- dummyVars[is.na(df$v1), 4:ncol(dummyVars)]


Naive_Bayes_Model=multinomial_naive_bayes(x = as.matrix(X_train), 
                                          y = y_train)

# predict missing data
Naive_Bayes_preds = predict(Naive_Bayes_Model, 
                                  newdata = as.matrix(X_to_impute))


# fill in predictions
df$multinom_preds[is.na(df$v1)] = as.character(predictions)
df$Naive_Bayes_preds[is.na(df$v1)] = as.character(Naive_Bayes_preds)
head(df, 15)
```

```
#         v1 v2 v3 multinom_preds Naive_Bayes_preds
#    1     a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    2     a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    3     a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    4     c p2 o2           <NA>              <NA>
#    5     e p3 o3           <NA>              <NA>
#    6 <NA> p1 o1              a                 a
#    7     a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    8     a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    9     a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    10    c p2 o2           <NA>              <NA>
#    11    e p3 o3           <NA>              <NA>
#    12 <NA> p1 o1              a                 a
#    13    a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    14    a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
#    15    a p1 o1           <NA>              <NA>
```

Comment: KNN is a good idea but I need something a more effcient than KNN. I forgot to mention that my data has more than a million rows :/ Thank you so much anyways!

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with some new ideas that will work for large data sets.

Comment: Thanks Cailin. One more question, why did you use this formula (v1 ~ (v2+ v3)^2 in multinom function? Do you think multinomial log linear models vía neural networks would work well for a dataset with just categorical variables?

Comment: `(v2+ v3)^2` is R shorthand for `v1 + v2 + v1:v2` (i.e. the v1, v2 and the interaction).  The interaction may not be necessary in this case -- it may be more useful for more complicated relationships. A neural network would also work, but the training time may become an issue, depending on the size of the data set and the architecture of the network (among other things).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Oops. I made a typo above. `(v2+ v3)^2` is R shorthand for `v2 + v3 + v2:v3`. Also, here's a link that explains the model formula better: (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have access to GPU's you can check out [DataWig from AWS Labs](https://github.com/awslabs/datawig) to do deep learning-driven categorical imputation. You can experiment with batch sizes (depending on the available GPU memory) and hyperparameter optimization. You can specifically choose [categorical encoders](https://github.com/awslabs/datawig/blob/master/examples/imputer_intro.py) with [embedding](https://datawig.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/userguide.html?highlight=EmbeddingFeaturizer#featurizer-mxnet-input-symbol-py).

As a sidenote, there is also the algorithm MICE (Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations). [Miceforest](https://pypi.org/project/miceforest/) is one example of a library that runs on CPU's by default. However, the backend uses LightGBM (Gradient Boosting Machine) for random forests classification. You can pass a couple of parameters to the `.tune_parameters()` function from miceforest when LightGBM was [built for GPU's](https://www.kaggle.com/vinhnguyen/gpu-acceleration-for-lightgbm/notebook). For example, `device="gpu",gpu_platform_id=0,gpu_device_id=0`, etc. More info on how to optimize GPU-performance can be found here https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Performance.html.